# How do you execute a terminal command and then repeatedly check and store the response in Python?

Tags: python

I have a terminal command that is to be run once. Basically, when you execute the command, the program runs continuously until told otherwise. While the program is running, it will keep outputting strings of text into the terminal. I would like to somehow store these strings as a variable so I can check to see if it contains specific keywords.
I tried using os.system, but alas, that does not store the response from the program.
Thanks in advance, and I'm sorry for my naivety

Comment: Is the response being sent to STDOUT/STDERR? `subprocess` module exposes a `check_output` function which returns the text of STDOUT/STDERR that you may be able to parse. (ie, `subprocess.check_output(arg).split("\n")`)

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3991104/very-large-input-and-piping-using-subprocess-popen

Comment: @AnthonyForloney - do not do that. check_output buffers the entire output, and then returns it after the command has finished.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To spawn a subprocess running a command, use `subprocess.Popen`:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['cat', 'myfile'], stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
```

By setting `stdout` to `PIPE`, you'll make `cat` output text through a channel that you control.

When `Popen` returns, `proc.stdout` will be a `file-like` object that you can `read()`. It also exposes `readline()`, for convenience.

`readline()` returns the next line of the stream, `\n` at the end included. When it returns `''`, there's nothing left to read.

```
line = proc.stdout.readline()

while line != '':
    print line
```

You can also create a line iterator to walk the output line by line. You can give this iterator to other functions, that can then consume the output of your subprocess without interacting with the process object directly:

```
iterator = iter(proc.stdout.readline, '')

# Somewhere else in your program...
for line in iterator:
    print line
```

Comment: Very insightful, thank you. Im afraid i do get an error with the parameters of Popen. When i use stdout=subprocess.PIPE it gives me an error. Is it supposed to be stdout=PIPE instead?

Comment: @A_toaster how did you import `subprocess`? If you did `import subprocess.Popen` or `from subprocess import Popen` then the `PIPE` variables won't work. Just do `import subprocess` and you'll have access to all of its components.