# How to use Popen to read a json file in subprocess as there is a 33766 limit in terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x, curl, subprocess, grpc

I am using this code to read a json file in subprocess. It does work for only small jsons, If it exceeds over 33766 count. it will show a error showing

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 206] The filename or extension is too long.
```

this is beccause of exceeding 33766 count. so how to read the json file using popen .Read that this can solve the problem. Help me with suggestions. I am new here :\

```
import subprocess
import json
import os

from pprint import pprint

auth = "authorization: token 1234

file = "jsoninput11.json"
fd=open("jsoninput11.json")
json_content = fd.read()
fd.close()


subprocess.run(["grpcurl", "-plaintext","-H", auth,"-d","@",json_content,"-format","json","100.20.20.1:5000","api.Service/Method"])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure but maybe the problem is related to the `bufsize` (check this:
[Very large input and piping using subprocess.Popen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3991104/very-large-input-and-piping-using-subprocess-popen) )
Does it works with `capture_output=False`?

```
subprocess.run(["grpcurl", "-plaintext","-H", auth,"-d","@",json_content,"-format","json","100.20.20.1:5000","api.Service/Method"], capture_output=False)
```

On the other side, if you need the output you may need to deal with the PIPE of Popen.

Comment: same error.  My json file  has around   3000 lines .

Comment: I see, maybe you can try this, if it doesn't work then I cannot help, sorry.
Remove the `capture_output=False`.
Open a file:
`f = open("blah.txt", "w")` then add in your "run" `stdout=f`.  This will redirect the stdout to the file.